# Azure - SQL Sync - Windows Server 2008 R2 - Buggy?

Tags: sql-server, windows, synchronization, azure-sql-database

Are there people out there using Windows Server 2008 R2 + SQL Server 2008 R2 and have successfully synced the database from localhost to the cloud on Azure? My goal is to give preference to the local machine database, and I want the cloud database to by in sync with whatever's on the local machine.

First off I had a hard time downloading dependencies, but after getting past that, I'm still getting errors (bugs?), or hopefully am I doing something wrong with getting the client sync agent to load?

I downloaded the "SQLDataSyncAgent-Preview-ENU.msi" file. I'm entering my local box administrator password but I get an error "Service MS SQL Data Sync could not be installed. verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services". Are you guys using some special account you're creating separately instead of using the local admin?

Comment: I figured it out - my computer name was 16 characters as displayed in the MY COMPUTER -> Properties area, but this tool needed to be supplied with the first 15 characters before the /Administrator! Resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This and other similar issues are discussed with solution in the Forum:

[Unable to install MS SQL Azure Data Sync (Preview)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/8c967fd1-b952-4f79-87ca-98027cac4719)

Comment: Thanks.. I did figure out the issue right after my post though. Unfortunately, I have now moved to Amazon AWS, I was having many other issues with T-SQL and .BAK limitations in Azure.